# How to push messages from API server (PHP/rest) to C# apps

Tags: c#, php, web-services, streaming, push

I have C# apps requesting data from PHP/MySQL API server (Rest/JSON). Now I also need to push messages to the C# apps when some events occur (form submission from the web site). I searched around, and it seems that COMET, long polling, and http streaming are options. Could you please provide some suggestions on which technology makes sense here, as I am not pushing to a web browser?

In addition, if using HTTP streaming (like twitter streaming API), do I need to keep a table of HTTP connections so I know which connection to use when pushing targeted events (only to certain C# clients)? I am a bit confused, and many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make a WCF Web Service.  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFWebService.aspx

To connect using PHP: http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2007/09/17/using-wcf-services-with-php.aspx

Comment: Are you suggesting to make my C# side act as WCF web service and having my API server to connect to them? The problem is that these C# clients may be behind firewalls or NAT, and I don't necessarily know how many of them and where they are (no control). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In micro-services environment you might want to communicate between more different coding languages in the future, that's why in Kaltura we expose every API with descriptive [XML](http://www.kaltura.com/api_v3/api_schema.php) that we can use later to [generate](https://github.com/kaltura/clients-generator) client libraries in multiple coding languages, our code generator includes client libraries for C# and PHP.
I also published several REST server examples, [including C#](https://restafar.com/c-very-simple-rest-server/).